# Android Oreo black screen in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation, android-8.0-oreo

I am using the 2.3.3 version of Android Studio in Windows 10. In AVD every virtual device is able to run all verisons of android except Oreo. After starting the emulator with Android 8.0( API level 26) the ram usage of emulator stops around 400-410MB and then nothing happens, just a mobile screen with black screen even without a loading animation. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue. Could you please tell if you're able to go past this problem?

Comment: No, I think the problem is with the image, waiting for 8.1 Image.

Comment: Thanks! Even I think so, I was about to try 8.1 image. Another option is to try on mac machine after updating HAXM driver. But, I will prefer to try with 8.1 on my windows machine.

Comment: 8.1 image works fine!!!

Comment: Thanks for telling. I am going to try it. :)

Answer (score 0):

***Step 1***- Made a new emulator(Any).

***Step 2***- then fixed another problem the black screen by changing the settings to use hardware graphics.(Dunno if this problem was related to the bug)